# jQuery add "close & open" container to split list

Tags: jquery, split, containers, appendto, insertafter

I'm trying to split a list via `jQuery`. I need a fix, because otherwise the navigation will crash my theme.

Here's my code, I've already tried several things like `append`, `after` and `insertAfter`. **The problem is that jQuery always adds the closing and reopen tag in the right order, but I need it the other way**:

```
<ul>
<li>link here</li>
<li>link here</li>
<li>link here</li>
<li>link here</li>
</ul>
```

this is what i want:

```
<ul>
<li>link here</li>
<li>link here</li>
</ul><ul>
<li>link here</li>
<li>link here</li>
</ul>
```

this is my code so far:

```
var thirdLevelNavigation = $('ul.sub-menu').clone();
var countItems = 0;
thirdLevelNavigation.children('li').each(function() {                                       
    if(countItems == 5) {
        // heres the trouble-maker
        $('</ul><ul class="sub-menu">').insertAfter(this);
        countItems = 0;
    }                                       
    countItems++;                               
});                                 
thirdLevelNavigation.appendTo('.menu-main-container');
```

(its a sub-nav tweak for multi dimensional wordpress navigations)

TIA!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dURwk/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ul = $('ul');
var items= ul.children();
for (var i= 0; i<items.length-2; i+= 2)
    items.slice(i, i+2).appendTo( $('<ul>').insertBefore(ul) );
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dURwk/10/)